# Pandas group by gender shows more than two groups

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe that shows each audience's ranking for a bunch of movies. I wanted to make a list of movies with the most ratings, for each gender.
Here's what I did:

```
most_rated_gen=lens.groupby(['sex','title']).size().sort_values(ascending=False).to_frame()
```

I was expecting to see a dataframe that looks something like this:

```
sex | title
M     A
      B
      C
      D
F     B
      C
      D
      A
```

Instead, I got this:
[image: result]

I don't know why it shows M F M F M. Any ideas how I could fix this?

Comment: Because you group by `sex`?

Answer (score 1):

As you group by `sex`, the output will contain the `sex` column.
You have a shortcut for your operation with `value_counts`:

```
df.value_counts(['sex', 'title']).sort_index(kind='mergesort')
```

If you want your data to be sorted by index while preserving the order of values then you have to use `sort_index` with `kind='mergesort'` as parameter.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `nlargest()` if your `aggregated` column has a name. Assuming the column name is `ratings_count`. You can use this code.

```
most_rated_gen.groupby(['sex'])['ratings_count'].nlargest()
```

[Source](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/pandas-groupby-sort-within-groups/)